# "No handler found" while loading OpenERP 7 on localhost

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have been working on a custom module of [OpenERP 7](https://www.openerp.com/) on localhost:8069, but today when I try to load the OpenERP7 on localhost it is giving me the error "no handler found". I dont' understand the problem because db postgresql is working fine. I'd rather not reinstall the application.

Comment: How did you start OpenERP? Have you checked the log? "No handler found" is usually caused by wrong "openerp-web" path configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Check with openerp-server.log. it's generally caused when your server is unable to start properly. Reason could be anything, any buggy module, missing library etc.

Answer (score 0):

I simply replaced the addons folder and it worked for me i suspect there are modules i had installed that had bugs